My Ubuntu 23.04 is out of date. trying to upgrade to ubuntu 23.10. but it says "Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore."
I get the upgrade suggestion. but it doesn't upgrading.
it says -
$ update-manager
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

how can i upgrade to latest version without fresh installing?
.enter image description here

You need to apply all upgrades; however due to your release being EOL, mirrors are free to drop support, and the main archive is moved as was announced would happen soon after EOL (see https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/) thus you need to correct your sources to apply all upgrades.  Apply all upgrades as per messages (after adjusting sources to match the EOL system you have, ie. switched from any dropped sources etc)

If in future you don't want the hassle of adjusting sources due to EOL, do the release-upgrade before on on the day of the EOL, and not afterwards... esp. this far after. There is no set number of days before dropping occurs; except it'll occur after the EOL.
